# Mapping class and properties between ontologies

Tags: mapping, rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I have three big RDF data dump described with three different ontologies (let's call them A, B and C), and I would like to map some classes and properties together in order to link and query them.

Further detail of the use case:

The three ontology have all a class about Agents, but they treat the agent differently:

Ontology A treats them as Agent (class x)
Ontology B treats them as subclass of subject (aboutness) (class y)
Ontology C treats them as resource of an authority file (class z)

Would love to express that the individual in class y and z are also individual of class x.

The easiest way would be to create a light top ontology D, map each of the classes and subclasses of A, B and C to D and then query D. However, I would like to use ontology A as main one.

Another solution would be to define classes and properties of B and C as subclass and sub properties of A. While this solution could work, I wonder if there would be a better one which would not leave me with an ontological mess at the end of the process.

How can I express that Class x from ontology A is the class of all the individual from Class x from A, Class y from B and Class z and z' from C ?

owl:equivalentClass and owl:equivalentProperty do not seems to fit because it defines that two classes/properties have the same extension. In this case the extension of Class x from A should be equal to

Class x from A + Class y from B + Class z from C + Class z' from C

but it should not (preferably) entail that:

Class y from B = Class x from A + Class y from B + Class z from C + Class z' from C
and
Class z from C = Class x from A + Class y from B + Class z from C + Class z' from C

Because i would also declare that the agent described by Class x from A are resource of an authority file (which they are not).

Any ideas?

owl:unionOf could be another solutions, but what about the properties?

Comment: I am not sure why equivalentClass and equivalentProperty do not work, but maybe I don't understand your use case. I have a slight suspicion you may be thinking of extension in a closed-world fashion, when in fact OWL is open world. It doesn't matter if A, B and C assert different individuals for x, y and z, so long as you are OK with all individuals asserted to be of type x being entailed to be individuals of class y and individuals of class z. Perhaps give a concrete example of why this doesn't work for you?

Comment: It doesn't matter if A, B and C assert different individuals for x, y and z, so long as you are OK with all individuals asserted to be of type x being entailed to be individuals of class y and individuals of class z <-- that's exactly what I am not very much comfortable with. Would love to say that individual of type y and z are also individual of x but individual of x are not individual of y and z.

Comment: owl:equivalentClass is stronger then rdfs:subClassOf because it entails a subsumption in both directions. Simply use rdfs:subClassOf/rdfs:subPropertyOf from B to A and C to A which will entail that members of y and z are aslo members of x but not vice versa.